ASCII 2D landscape
You are given an input string, called path, consisting of u, d and s characters (i.e. uusduudsdduu):

u go up - Move up and output /
d go down - Move down and output \
s stay - output _ if the last movement was down (\), ‾ (overline) otherwise, on the same line

All paths start with an upward movement u.
Your task is to generate the 2D landscape resulting from the given path and print it.
Example:
uusduudsdduu
     /\_
 /‾\/   \  /
/        \/

The input character s should never trigger a vertical movement:
STAY after UP
 "...us..." -> .../‾...
STAY after DOWN
 "...ds..." -> ...\_...
STAY after STAY
 "...uss..." -> .../‾‾...
 "...dss..." -> ...\__...

This is a code-golf challenge, the shortest implementation in bytes wins.
Rules

The path has no constraints in terms of direction, extreme cases such as straight line or an upwards/downwards diagonal are valid inputs.
The height of the output must be minimal, without empty lines before, after or within the path. (it's possible to calculate the final height from the input string)
u, d and s can be substituted, but exactly 3 distinct characters must be used.
The character replacement for s is supposed to be different. The examples use _ and ‾, but the latter can be substituted with other characters if the language has issues with non-ASCII.


Does the height of the landscape always fit within a range? More concretely, can I always insert a number of newlines to get the desired image to display?

Is it possible for the canvas to go below the start height?

Can other input characters be used, or must it be d, s and u?

Are leading newlines (any number of) acceptable?

Is the character replacement for s supposed to be different, depending on whether it follows a u or a d?

We've had a similar challenge in the best, but with vertical output and no s. Can't figure out the right search terms to unearth it, though.

@Shaggy It's called "draw my downslashes"

May we use some other ASCII character e.g. -/~ instead of ‾? (some langs have trouble using non-ASCII)

That's the one. Thanks, @emanresuA.

I've VTCed this as unclear until the issue with the replacement character(s) for s is clarified.

The spec still doesn't actually specify much--most of the challenge has to be inferred from the examples, and the only explanation of what determines what character s produces is in a comment.

Charcoal, 33 bytes
≔_θＦＳ≡ιsθd«Ｍ⁼θ_↓\≔_θ»«Ｍ⌕θ_↓/≔‾θ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
≔_θ

Start by mapping s to _.
ＦＳ≡ι

Loop through and switch on each character of the input.
sθ

For an s just output its current mapping.
d«Ｍ⁼θ_↓\≔_θ»

For a d, move down if the mapping is _, then print a \ and set the mapping to _.
«Ｍ⌕θ_↓/≔‾θ

Otherwise, move up unless the mapping is _, then print a / and set the mapping to ‾ (which costs 3 bytes to represent in Charcoal).
Had it been acceptable to print an underline on the line above instead of an overline, then for 14 bytes:
ＦＳ≡ιd¦¶\¦s¦_↗/

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Depending on each input letter, the program either d) moves down a line, then prints a \ s) prints a _ or u) prints a /, then moves up a line. Annoyingly I can't seem to do anything about the multiple separators required between the strings which take up over 20% of my bytes.

According to the current spec, the replacement character for s should be different, depending on whether it follows a u or a d. The other 2 solutions have the same issue. I've asked for clarification on whether it's supposed to be different.

@Shaggy Thanks, I've added an answer which switches the s replacement character appropriately, and moved my original answer to be an alternative answer.

13 extra bytes? Ouch! Sorry.

C (in an xterm), 80 79 bytes
l(char*s){for(puts("\e[2J\e[99B");*s;)printf("/\e[A\0\e[B\\\0_"+(1^*s++&3)*5);}

Clears the terminal and draws a landscape at the bottom of the screen:


Perl 5 + -pF -M5.10.0, 35 bytes
say$/x@F;s/d/.\\/g;s!u!/.[A!g;y;s;_
Try it online!

According to the current spec, the replacement character for s should different, depending on whether it follows a u or a d. The other 2 solutions have the same issue. I've asked for clarification on whether it's supposed to be different.

@Shaggy It only says s shouldn't trigger vertical movement, and this code doesn't. But yeah, it's a bit unclear.

Z80 Machine Code, 39 bytes
1AB7C81323FE552005362F250600FE44200524365C065FFE5320E5A0200624367E2518DC7018D9

Without the requirement for the s character being different based on whether it follows a u or d, the code can be gotten down to 27 bytes.
Explanation of disassembled code:
; de = Pointer to input string. Hitting a null character causes the subroutine
;      to return. Characters other than 's', 'u', 'd' cause undefined behavior.
; hl = Pointer to starting location within output array, minus 1. The width of
;      the array must be 256 bytes.
DrawLandscape:
    ld a, (de)                  ; Get the character from the input string. If
    or a                        ; it's the null character, return.
    ret z

    inc de                      ; Increment both input and output pointers.
    inc hl

    cp 'u'                      ; If the character is 'u', draw a '/', move the
    jr nz, noUp                 ; pointer up a row, and set the lower straight
    ld (hl), '/'                ; value to 0, indicating a '~' will be drawn one
    dec h                       ; position below the pointer.
    ld b, 0
noUp:

    cp 'd'                      ; If the character is 'd', move the pointer down
    jr nz, noDown               ; a row, draw a '\', and set the lower straight
    inc h                       ; value to '_', which we draw later.
    ld (hl), '\'
    ld b, '_'
noDown:

    cp 's'                      ; If the character is 's', we need to draw a
    jr nz, DrawLandscape        ; straight character.

    and b                       ; If the lower straight value is not set, we
    jr nz, drawLower            ; need to draw a '~' below the pointer.

    inc h
    ld (hl), '~'
    dec h
    jr DrawLandscape
drawLower:

    ld (hl), b                  ; Otherwise, draw the lower straight value
    jr DrawLandscape            ; directly.

There's no portable way to print stuff in Z80, but here's an example of the code in action:


C (GCC) in a terminal, 185 183 bytes
h;w;d;W;i;p;main(m,v)char**v,*m;{for(W=strlen(*++v)+1,m=calloc(W*3,W);w[*v];m[(++h+d+!d+W)*W+w++]="\\_/"[d])h-=d=w[*v]-100>>3;for(;i<3*W*W;putchar(++i%W?w?:32:p?p=0,10:13))p|=w=m[i];}

Attempt This Online!
C (GCC) with many empty lines, 171 169 bytes
h;w;d;W;i;main(m,v)char**v,*m;{for(W=strlen(*++v)+1,m=calloc(W*3,W);w[*v];m[(++h+d+!d+W)*W+w++]="\\_/"[d])h-=d=w[*v]-100>>3;for(;i<3*W*W;putchar(++i%W?w?:32:10))w=m[i];}

Attempt This Online!

-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

In ATO, both versions output many empty lines. The first version does not print empty lines when run in a terminal.

Zsh --extendedglob in xterm, 141 bytes
Inspired by G. Sliepen's C answer, but fixed to follow us → /‾ and make ud/du not unnecessarily switch lines.
For fairness, this also sends \e[2J\e[99B to clear screen and move cursor down 99 lines, just as in their answer.
<<<$'\e[2J\e[99B'
m=(u '\e[A' d '\e[B')
for c
printf ${${c#[^$v]}:+$m[1+m[(i)$c]]}${${${c/u//}/d/\\}/s/${${${v#d}:+‾}:-_}}&&v=${${c#s}:-$v}

Don't try it online, it doesn't work there!

Zsh --extendedglob in xterm, 78 bytes
Same idea as G. Sliepen's C answer, both of our answers don't follow spec for us → /‾. ~~I think I have an idea to fix it though. EDIT: See above.
m=(u $'/\e[A' d $'\e[B\\' s _)
<<<$'\e[2J\e[99B'${1//(#m)?/$m[m[(i)$MATCH]+1]}

Don't try it online, it doesn't work there!
